# Two submits in one JPS and two actions in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I know this question has been asked and answered but I don`t seems to have found a solution.

```
<form:form method="post" action="my.htm" modelAttribute="someForm">
    <div class="rightAlign"><input type="submit" value="something" name="something"/></div>
    <div class="rightAlign"><input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete"/></div>
</form:form>
```

How should I map it in controller?

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params="/delete")
```

or

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/something")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form's `action` corresponds to RequestMapping's `value` parameter, `name` of the input field will be used as the name of the HTTP parameter, use the `params` element to "catch" it. The correct RequestMapping configuration to filter by form's content would be:

```
@RequestMapping(value="my.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="delete")
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value="my.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="something")
```

(It's all in the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#annotation_type_optional_element_summary))